# React material ui autocomplete hooks

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm using the material UI autocomplete in react and it's working fine.

However, I can't figure out how to get the object of the selected item. Ex I want to search for a person and then add that item to an array of objects, and into a table. The person object including name, email and so on.

And I can't seem to find any examples of this.

My code looks like this:
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN5AE.png)

I trying:
https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

Does anyone have an Idé on how to do this? I'm pretty new to react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onChange property of Autocomplete and find object by id in the array of options.

Comment: Thanks solved it, I used onChange on the autocompleted. I saw result by using         onChange={(e, i) => console.log(i)}